# Getting percentage of 1's in each column in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

i have a DF like so:

```
row_id   stn_1 stn_2 stn_3 stn_4 stn_5
1        1     0     1     0     1
2        0     1     0     0     0
3        1     0     0     0     0
4        1     0     1     0     0
5        0     0     0     1     0
```

I want to get the percentage of stn's that appeared in the data. basically the percentage of 1's in each column except row_id.

expected output:

```
stn    percentage
stn_1  .60
stn_2  .20
stn_3  .40
stn_4  .20
stn_5  .20
```

How can I do this in dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As stated by @akrun we also can use `plyr::numcolwise(mean)(df[-1]) %>% gather()`

**First answer:**
Here is one more. Honestly @MrFlick the idea with the mean was fantastic!!!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-row_id, ~sum(.)/nrow(df))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("stn") %>% 
  select(stn, percentage=X1)
```

```
    stn percentage
1 stn_1        0.6
2 stn_2        0.2
3 stn_3        0.4
4 stn_4        0.2
5 stn_5        0.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much master! I will add it to my answer!

Answer (score 5):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do

```
dd %>% 
  summarize(across(-row_id, mean)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to="stn", values_to="percentage", everything())
#   stn   percentage
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 stn_1        0.6
# 2 stn_2        0.2
# 3 stn_3        0.4
# 4 stn_4        0.2
# 5 stn_5        0.2
```

The `summarize` does the calculation and the `pivot_longer` does the reshaping.

Answer (score 2):

What about `colMeans` with a bit of tibble `enframe`-ing? (not `dplyr` but maybe close enough)

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  select(-row_id) |>
  colMeans() |>
  enframe(name = "stn", value = "percentage")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  stn     percentage
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 stn_1   0.6
2 stn_2   0.2
3 stn_3   0.4
4 stn_4   0.2
5 stn_5   0.2
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_table("row_id   stn_1 stn_2 stn_3 stn_4 stn_5
1        1     0     1     0     1
2        0     1     0     0     0
3        1     0     0     0     0
4        1     0     1     0     0
5        0     0     0     1     0")
```

Comment: in base R `stack(colMeans(subset(df, ,-row_id)))` if you know the position `stack(colMeans(df[-1]))`